# Django form manytomany field not saving to database

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and i am working on a website where user can submit a post. Django Form is not saving in database when i have manytomany field in model. I do not know if i can achieve this in Django, I want to attached other user names to the post so that when i submit the form the user name is selected automatically when i check on the post in admin. I will attach a screenshots for clarity.

This image below is my form, as you can see 'My post' is the image_caption while 'andy' is another user name, i want 'andy' selected automatically in manytomany field when form is submitted.

[image]

This is what i want when the form is submitted then i check in admin. The other user name (andy) is selected in manytomany field when the form is submitted. I did this manually

[image]

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', default="ProfilePicture/user-img.png", blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    poster_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    image_caption = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_someone = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='tagged_users', blank=True)
```

Forms:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'image_caption', 
            'tag_someone',
        )
```

Views:

```
def upload_view(request):
    ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(File, fields=('files',), extra=20)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.poster_profile = request.user
            post.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            for f in formset:
                try:
                    photo = File(post=post, files=f.cleaned_data['files'])
                    photo.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    break
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = PostForm()
        formset = ImageFormset(queryset=File.objects.none())

    #User Name Auto-complete In Tag Form
    all_users = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True) 

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
        'all_users': all_users,
    }
    return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

Upload.html:

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  {{ formset }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block w-25">Post</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: For what I think, you are using custom user model so you have to use the auth_user_model to get the user in tag_someone field as well.

Comment: @ngawang... I have updated my question, i added my profile model. What should i do to achieve this?

Comment: i mean in you tag_someone field you are trying to get the user form user model but did u create one. If not user setting.auth_user_model to get the user instead of User

Comment: @ngawang..I have done that, but the form is not submi and also not saving to database. When I click on post, it reload the same page.

Comment: Try saving the form and formset separately and see which one is creating the problem. I think the formset is not saving you form if so check for formset.errors.

Comment: @ngawang.. I do not understand what you mean, can you explain with a code? I have both form saved without adding Manytomany field in Post model, but when I add Manytomany field in Post model, form refuses to save.

Comment: @ngawang.. The form submits now and everything works fine. But I will have to make changes, the tag input changes to a select field with options, how do I change a select field to an input field, so that I can type text to get the username on manytomany field. If you have any suggestions or link I can get help from, you can drop it here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by changing widget to:

```
widget = { 
    forms.Select(),
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the widget here. Widgets are the thing that is responsible for outputting the inputs to HTML. So you just need:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = (
        'image_caption', 
        'tag_someone',
    )
  widgets = {'tag_someone': forms.TextInput}
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it working by changing widget.